# INSERT EXEC from DbCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm  trying to execute the results of a stored procedure that takes parameters into a temporary table.

```
// Create #temptable
// ..

using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT #temptable EXEC [MystoredProcThatHasParams]";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(someObject)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Output:

> Could not find stored procedure ''.

If I remove `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`, I get:

> Procedure or function 'MystoredProcThatHasParams' expects parameter '@p1' which was not supplied

Is it possible to save the output of a stored procedure that takes parameters from a query in C#?

Comment: I assume you're missing a `string.Format` or something in there?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield ha yeah, copy/paste errors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command type `StoredProcedure` uses a special, higher-performance method for connecting to SQL Server (an RPC call), which requires that the command text be *exactly* the name of a stored procedure. You cannot include Transact-SQL in the command text if you want to use `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Instead, you need to use `CommandType.Text` and embed the parameters into the SQL string yourself:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT #temptable EXEC [MystoredProcThatHasParams] @Param1, @Param2";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "Test";
```

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. It would only be true if the table was created inside this command, for example from a `select * into #temptable from Foo where Foo.Bar = @bar`, but `INSERT` requires the table to pre-exist and this command will not affect its existence. `#temp` style tables exist for as long as the connection is open or you leave the stored procedure it was created in (if it was created inside a stored procedure)

Comment: If the connection that created the table is the same connection that has the executed command there is no need to worry about connection pooling, the statement *"they are reset between SQL calls"* is just pain wrong. The connection is only returned to the pool and has its state reset **when it is closed**. From the OP's example I think it is fairly safe to assume that `// Create #temptable` uses the same `connection` object and connection was not closed between the two steps.